# Activate User account for Sub Site broken

Tags: multisite, user-registration, activation

When I add a new user to a WP Multisite sub-site, an email is sent out asking the user to click a link to activate. The link looks like this:

https://website.com/subsite/wp-activate.php?key=XXXXXXXXX

When I click on it I get a 404 error. If I remove the "/subsite" part of the url (https://website.com/wp-activate.php?key=XXXXXXXXX), the user activation works, but it takes the user to the main site. I need the user to activate their new account on the subsite.

I am using Wordpress installed on IIS/Windows server.

Answer (score 0):

For subsite only registration this is not possible with Wordpress by default have a look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/network-subsite-user-registration/